# How to remove link between Azure AppInsights and an App Service via PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-application-insights

I have one AppInsights resource that serves a series of app services (each app service represents an isolated test environment). We spin up and destroy these app services via PowerShell.

App services are linked to AppInsights via hidden tags. If you delete an App Service, the hidden tag is not automatically deleted. A resource has an upper limit of 15 tags, which means that I must remove these tags from AppInsights when an environment is destroyed.

I can view the tags like this:

```
PS Azure:\> $AppInsights = Get-AzureRmApplicationInsights -ResourceGroupName "foo" -Name "bar";

PS Azure:\> $AppInsights.Tags;

Key                                                                                    Value
---                                                                                                                                                                  -----
hidden-link:/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/foo/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/xxx    Resource
...
```

So I can edit that hashtable, but there seems to be no way of persisting the changes back to Azure through PowerShell.

Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way for this. But you can use `Set-AzureRmResource` to achieve this.

First, you can use `Get-AzureRmApplicationInsights  -ResourceGroupName "xxx" -Name "xxx"` to get the properties of your app insights, note that the Type which will be used later:

[image]

And I also can see that I have 5 tags:

[image]

And I want to remove the one ends with "`appInsightsdemo11`"

The sample code as below(you can modify to meet your exact needs):

```
$a = Get-AzureRmApplicationInsights  -ResourceGroupName "xxx" -Name "xxx"

$b = $a.tags

# use $new_tags to store the tags which are not deleted
$new_tags=@{}

# if the key does not contain "appInsightsdemo11", it will not be deleted.
$b.Keys | %{ if(!$_.contains("appInsightsdemo11")){$new_tags.Add($_, $b[$_])}}

# then update the tags which does not have the one "appInsightsdemo11"
Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "xxx" -ResourceName "xxx" -Tag $new_tags -force -ResourceType microsoft.insights/components
```

After the above command done, run the cmdlet `Get-AzureRmApplicationInsights` again. And you can see the tags contains "appInsightsdemo11" has been removed.

[image]